# Круглый SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, swipe

Добрый день! Подскажите плиз такую вещь. В Android есть такой контрол для обновления данных который называется SwipeRefreshLayout. Как я понял до версии API 21 этот контрол выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а после версии 21 выглядит уже круглым. То есть так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли использовать круглый SwipeRefreshLayout в врсиях Android ниже 21-ой? На некоторых приложениях я видел такое и хотел бы сделать тоже самое и в своем приложении. Подскажите плиз как это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Скачайте последнюю версию android-support-library.

2) Добавьте её к проекту

3) В разметке используйте

> android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Теперь у вас "кружок" на версия андроида < Lolipop.